# How to add to an existing plot a marker for points in the chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker

So hello community,
I have a program which includes several functions and they all have 5-6 fix points. On those points i always want to have whether a square or diamond marker style. I can do it in the program but i want to have it in the script so they already appear when i run the program. ANy ideas?

Comment: Well..set the marker styles in the script during plotting, and use `plt.show()` to make the plot appear. Otherwise your question is unclear. What's your difficulty?

Comment: Okay i find out the solution and yeah probably my question is a bit unclear :D

Comment: I'm glad you did:) Since you solved your question, I suggest that you delete it (as it doesn't have any answers, and won't need any in the future).

Comment: I did add an answer so anybody with the same question finds easily the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is described on this website and much more.
https://bespokeblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/basic-data-plotting-with-matplotlib-part-2-lines-points-formatting/

basically the command is just:

```
ax1f1.plot(x, y, marker='s', linestyle='-', color='k')
```

Comment: The answer is also in the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) :P